# Facebook API error: (OAuthException) An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing an apps which enable me to post to Group's wall via my web apps. But i get the following errors: (OAuthException) An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

```
            var client = new FacebookClient("<my token>");
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.access_token = "<my token>";
            parameters.message = "testing";
            parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
            parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
            parameters.name = "Article Title";
            parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
            parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
            parameters.actions = new
            {
                name = "View on Zombo",
                link = "http://www.zombo.com",
            };
            dynamic result = client.Post("/<group id>/feed", parameters);
```

I get the following result in https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token="my token"

```
 {
 "data": [
  {
     "installed": 1,
     "status_update": 1,
     "photo_upload": 1,
     "video_upload": 1,
     "create_note": 1,
     "share_item": 1,
     "read_stream": 1,
     "publish_stream": 1,
     "manage_pages" : 1
  }
]}
```

Did I miss any other permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code appears to be correct. And if you have a valid access token with the 'publish_stream' permission this request should work. The one thing I was wondering about was if setting the access token twice was causing a problem, but I looked through the code and it looks like it shouldn't. Try changing your code to the below example and see if it works.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(); / Node no token in constructor
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.access_token = "<my token>";
parameters.message = "testing";
parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
parameters.name = "Article Title";
parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
parameters.actions = new
{
    name = "View on Zombo",
    link = "http://www.zombo.com",
};
dynamic result = client.Post("/<group id>/feed", parameters);
```

We are going to double check this in the SDK, but if this works for you please create a bug on github as your above code should work correctly.

Comment: Any follow up on this? I'm having the same error right now, and it was working two days ago. (OAuthException) An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later